# Can you concentrate alcohol by evaporating the aqueous solution at room temp and collecting on a cold surface?

Tags: vapor-pressure

I have a bowl containing cheap wine and an immersible fish tank heater. The heater warms the wine to 30 deg C. The bowl is located in a large closed bucket, where it sits on a support. The bucket is sited out of doors in winter when the air temperature is Ca 1 deg C. Evaporation occurs and the vapour condenses on the inner surface of the bucket. Droplets of condensate run down and form a pool of liquid on the floor of the bucket.

Question: what can be predicted about the composition of the condensate?

Question #2 What effect is achieved by raising or lowering the temperature of the wine on the composition of the condensate. In plain language what temperature of the wine will give me the highest concentration of alcohol in the condensate? How can the strength of the alcohol be measured?

Question #3 What is the effect of different air temperatures outside of the bucket (on the composition of the condensate)?

Question #4 Why is this method not commonly used to concentrate alcohol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, this technique is called 'distillation' (it requires a minimum difference of 10 degrees celsius to seperate two liquids with different boiling points, for efficiency), I don't know what temeperature the fish tank heater runs at, but you should know that ethanol i,e. what you are trying to separate evaporates at 37 degrees celsius same as normal body temperature, and the temperature of the cooling plate should be < 27 degrees **for efficiency**

Edit -
yes, exactly the boiling point of ethanol is 78.3 degrees but ethanol is highly volatile and evaporates very fast at 37 degrees (without taking much water vapour with it) as far as my observation is concerned(with room temperature around, 1 atm pressure). the values I mentioned are the optimal conditions with experimental background. your goal as I can percieve is to avoid as much water as possible, if you take the condenser temperature to below 10 degrees the water vapour present in air will also start to condense at a good rate

Comment: I have set the fish tank heater to 30 deg C, but I could set it as low as 20 deg C. How would the lower temperature affect the composition of the condensate? The "cooling plate" (the walls of the bucket) are at, or close to, the external air temp which is currently 1 deg C. So there is a  29 degree difference between the wine and the condensing surface. If the weather gets colder (the differential increases) how does this affect the condensate?

Comment: << ethanol . . . evaporates at 37 degrees celsius>> My understanding is that ethanol _boils_ at 78.3 C. but I am concerned with _evaporation_, which I think can occur at any temperature above the solid state (frozen ethanol) not solely at the 37 degrees you mention. The point of my question is to see if different conditions can improve the process in the aim of achieving a higher ABV.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.  Can you elaborate as to the other aspects of the questions the OP asked?

Comment: 37 degrees celsius is a temperature for efficiency under room temperature i.e, 25 degrees. I have myself experienced the values experimentally in lab

Comment: the temperature difference mentioned by the questioner should also work efficiently, the only problem here is that if the setup is open to air it might condense water from air as well.

Comment: @jonsca, As far I can perceive the questioner is inquiring about distillation

Comment: yes exactly the boiling point of ethanol is 78.3 degrees but ethanol is highly volatile and evaporates very fast at 37 degrees (without taking much water vapour with it) as far as my observation is concerned(with room temperature around, 1 atm pressure). the values I mentioned are the optimal conditions with experimental background. your goal as I can percieve is to avoid as much water as possible, if you take the condenser temperature to  below 10 degrees the water vapour present in air will also start to condense at a good rate.

Comment: yes testing it out would be really good, you can use 20 degrees plus temperature but less than 27 degrees.

Comment: <<37 degrees celsius is a temperature for efficiency under room temperature i.e, 25 degrees>> Please define what you mean by efficiency. I don't understand what the meaning of"under room temperature" might be in this context. Please explain.

Comment: Please note as originally stated, this operation takes place in a closed container (the atmosphere is excluded).

Comment: << if you take the condenser temperature to below 10 degrees the water vapour present in air will also start to condense at a good rate>> Can one predict by theory whether condensation of the vapor (the ethanol component) will occur at temperatures above  10 deg, or is experimentation the only way to know?

Comment: then you can dip the condenser temperature to 15 degrees any low again the water factor

Comment: not by theory not by calculating, its by both

Comment: <<then you can dip the condenser temperature to 15 degrees any low again the water factor>> For clarity, please state what you think are the best temperatures for my purpose. 1) Ethanol / water bath. 2) Condenser surface.

Comment: ETHANOL/WATER BATH 35 to 45 degrees and                              CONDENSER 15 to 20 degrees

Comment: if it did work please leave an update either in comments or in your answer, this helps future users

Comment: I have ordered an alcohol meter to measure the results. What I can say currently is that under the conditions of the first experiment (alcohol / water solution 30 C. , condenser 1 C.) concentration occurs but the output cannot be set alight - ie less than proof strength. I will report back when I have new data.

Comment: The alcohol hydrometer which I obtained gives only coarse indications for dilute concentrations. It indicated about 18% alcohol which was evaporated and condensed out of a 11% base, which was heated to 30C. Room temperature (the condenser surface) 17C. Production rate about 300 ml in 24 hours with my set-up. I don't have appropriate measuring equipment to see what the effects of varying the temps would be.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my principal question is that you can concentrate an aqueous ethanol solution by "room temperature distillation". I don't have the right equipment to be able to determine what variation in output quantity and strength might be obtained by varying the temperature of the source solution and the condenser surface. But I can state that the alcohol concentration in the condensate under the conditions I used finally was ca 18% coming from the source solution which was 11%. What I like about the process is that little energy is used for heating(30 watts) and no water is wasted for cooling as in conventional distillation.
Further experiment - from a wash of sugar and beer yeast using the method above I obtained a distillate which measured 36% on my $3 Russian alcohol hygrometer.

Comment: When you say "little energy is used" what you mean is that the *rate* of energy use is low. Given that the low temperature distillation will take a *lot* longer, I don't think you can comfortably say the total use is lower.